# bytearrayinputstream to string in Mule 4 using Java invoke static

Tags: java, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4, mule-connector

I want to get elements from an `.eml` file in Mule 4 using the Java Module invoke static operation, but it gives this error

```
Invocation of static Method 'Text(java.lang.String)' from Class 'testattach.Test' with arguments [org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider arg0] resulted in an error.
Expected arguments are [java.lang.String s].
Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException - javax.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart"
```

```
<java:invoke-static doc:name="Invoke static" doc:id="b668dd2d-c519-48e9-8293-a4725e19685d" class="testattach.Test" method="Text(java.lang.String)">
            <java:args ><![CDATA[#[{
    s : "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"
}]]]></java:args>
        </java:invoke-static>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your attachment data is encoded in base64 (should be the MIME base64 encoding system), so would need to be obtained from the message mail "Part" object and decoded to a byte array or String as allowable of the final output used data type.
In short, a MessagePart object of a mail message object is simply a cohesive part holder marking and containing the data required for it's Part type, Not the underlying byte data holder object type inside, so it cannot directly cast it. You must obtain it's data first from a method of the object that will retrieve that value.

The "initial mime bodypart object" should been "set to MultiPart" "this" so a MultiPart object requires using it's getCount() method to find the number of bodypart. Use the addBodyPart(. ) method of MultiPart to add message parts.

On the mail Part.ATTACHMENT Part use getContent() returns an Object and can be cast to it's corresponding  content-type (usually String) and use Base64.Encoder.getMimeEncoder().decode(String)

If you get a bytearrayinputstream it should read into a byte[] reference. Use new String(byte[]) to obtain the base64 string but a base64 decoder method can take a byte[] array as argument, but usually returns a byte[] of decoded bytes.

Answer (score 0):

As @Samuel Marchant mentioned the input is in base64. You can use the DataWeave Binaries module function `fromBase64()` to decode it before calling the Java method.

Assuming the input is in the payload (replace with whatever source you have) you replace the expression with the call to `fromBase64()`:

```js
{
   s: dw::core::Binaries::fromBase64(payload)
}
```